# UnicodeEncodeError греческая буква проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup, unicode, web-scraping

С Python начал знакомство недавно. Никак не могу решить проблему. Пытаюсь парсить сайт при помощи selenium. Страницу скачал, записал в файл. Файл в браузере открывается нормально. Хочу забрать список заголовков. Все забираются нормально, кроме одного, который содержит греческую букву бетта. При попытке вывести этот заголовок получаю ошибку "'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 13: character maps to ". Вроде и кодировку 'utf-8' прописал, а всё равно не работает. Файл страницы также записывал с использованием 'utf-8'

Полный текст ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\scrap\test1.py", line 18, in <module>
print(aaa.text)
File "C:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>
```

```
with open("index.html", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(driver.page_source)
```

, и в браузере он открывается нормально с написанием буквы 'бетта' как 'β'

```
with open("index.html", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    src = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
research = soup.find_all(class_="analyzes__row")
for res in research:
    res1 = res.find_all('a')
    for aaa in res1:
        try:
            print(aaa.text)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            continue
```

Comment: Вставьте точный текст ошибки  `"'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 13: character maps to "` без пропусков, еще лучше - с полным стектрейсом. Скорее всего выводите в консоль Windows, а она поддерживает не все символы.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\scrap\test1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(aaa.text)
  File "C:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Да, Windows. А можно как-то это исправить или windows никак не выведет эти символы? Может как-то заменить их перед выводом на другие?

Comment: Если это единичный случай, то просто через replace делать `text = aaa.text.replace("\u03b2", "бета")`. Если не единичный, то нужно смотреть какие еще встречаются символы, и от этого уже думать, что дальше делать.

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо оОоОгромное! Тут есть что-то типа кнопки "спасибо" и надо ли закрыть мой вопрос?

Comment: Сейчас оформлю ответом

Comment: Странно, в моей винде `print('\u03b2')` прекрасно работает

Comment: @CrazyElf скорее всего зависит от версии винды, настроек терминала. Если не включен юникодный шрифт в настройках, то скорее всего будет падать.

Comment: @insolor Так не правильнее ли как-раз таки включить юникодный шрифт, а не вот это вот всё? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, возможно правильнее, но у меня нет возможности проверить работоспособность этого варианта)

Comment: @CrazyElf, в общем я добавил в ответ первым пунктом, но не факт, что это на что-то повлияет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Первое, что стоит попробовать сделать - в настройках консоли включить юникодный шрифт (обычно можно выбрать Lucida Console, Consolas и другие). Если не помогло, смотрите другие пункты.
2. Если это единичный случай (другие юникодные символы не встречаются), то можно просто через `replace` заменить именно этот символ на что-то другое, пример:

   ```
   text = aaa.text.replace("\u03b2", "бета")
   print(text)
   ```
3. Можно результат парсинга писать в файл в кодировке utf-8, потом просматривать текстовым редактором с поддержкой этой кодировки.
4. Можно пробовать закодировать текст кодировкой cp1251 с параметром `errors="backslashreplace"`, потом декодировать той же кодировкой, тогда все юникодные символы, которые не удалось закодировать, преобразуются в вид `"\\u03b2"`:

   ```
   text = "Тестβ"
   text = text.encode("cp1251", errors="backslashreplace").decode("cp1251")
   print(text)  # Тест\u03b2
   ```

   Можно использовать не "backslashreplace", а "namereplace", тогда символ заменится на его имя, для беты это будет `\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA}`